# Go to Specified text in ul li based select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to have functionality such as that of select box, when using select box, if we type some keyword and that keyword happens to match in that select box, the pointer moves to the specified text, i want to achieve similar functionality here, following is my HTML

```
<a href="#" id="submit"> Get Value</a>
<ul>
    <li class="init">SELECT</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Following is my JS

```
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});


$("#submit").click(function() {
    alert("The selected Value is "+ $("ul").find(".selected").data("value"));
});
```

Following is my CSS

```
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out something like [**chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [**selectize**](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/). Download their files and add them to your site. if you go with Chosen you can initialize the plugin by adding `.chosen-select` to your form element:

```
<select class="chosen-select">
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>Whats Up</option>
  <option>How Are You</option>
  <option>Nice to See You</option>
  <option>Goodbye</option>
</select>
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6172jh6/7/)

Comment: there is a small problem here, the problem is that , i want to give this some what search facility to ul li based drop down , your example is referring to select box

Comment: No it's a select box that is converted to list-items. The plugin recreates your select options in a fully customizable styled `ul`. Its basically exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Yes no doubt it is an excellent plugin but the thing is that selectbox can only take text as parameters , but `<ul><li>` can use multiple elements and events, e.g lets say i want to show a tiny image , i cannot show it in select box.